# Sending transaction on test doesn't actually decrease balance

Tags: java, stellar

I'm using the Stellar Java SDK to try send some transaction on the test net.
The transaction seems to go through (no error) but when I check the balance of the sender of receiver, the balance is the same.

Is this normal behaviour on the testnet ?

Comment: I'm using the Stellar Javascript SDK and I'm having the same issue. The receiver balance does get updated, but the sender balance does not. I don't know if it's normal for being on the testnet.

Comment: do you have a link to such transaction (laboratory link for example)?

Answer (score 0):

The balance must always be decreased from the sender account by interacting with either the testnet or the public network unless the sender is the issuer. You need to create the trustline from the receiver on the issuer account instead of the base(distributor) account. That's because an asset is identified by a couple of elements: 1. the asset type(e.g. USD or BTC or whatever) and 2. the issuer(the account that created the asset). So for sure if you're not getting the sender balance updated after making the transaction, the reason is that you created the trustline from the receiver on the base account, and therefore in that case the base would be playing the rol to issuing a new type of asset.